# cannot load modules in js

Tags: javascript, module

When I try to load a module using require it works fine in terminal but doesn't work in browser:
`const express = require("express");`

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

Then I tried `import express from 'express';` and it says:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Then someone suggested to add `type="module"` to my script and it throws another error saying:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "express". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"
```

Basically, when I try to load a module it doesn't throw any error on vs code terminal but it does throw in browser console

```js
// JS

const express = require("express");

// Package.json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "p": "^0.2.0",
    "requirejs": "^2.3.6"
  },
  "name": "fetching-data",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```

```html
head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="main.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you making a static website or a nodejs app?

Comment: Basically, I'm just learning a little bit about node. But I got stuck in this silly problem from yesterday.

Comment: I think if you are learning about Nodejs, I think you need to run differently. This is for web Javascript modules which is a bit restricted to use on import or export only: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules

I think this is what you can get started with NodeJs: https://dev.to/cglikpo/getting-started-with-nodejs-130h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nodejs apps are different from static websites.

It does not work by loading scripts into an html file.

Read this [Nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/getting-started-guide/)
to get started with node development.

Comment: Thank you very much, you cleared my confusion and I solved that problem.